# Spawning a thread from a thread

Tags: python, multithreading

I am using python 3.4.2 to

1. let a thread (t1) from a list of threads processes some data
2. have t1 spawn another thread (t2) to do additional processing

The problem is that `proc_q1` appears to be called properly adding ids the  t2_q, but the t2 threads are not picking up the tasks from the queue before the `exit_flag` is set to `True`. Why doesn't `proc_q2` ever get called?

Here's some mock code

```
import urllib.request
import threading

from queue import Queue
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
from urllib.parse import urlparse

class Scanner(object):
    @staticmethod
    def proc_q1(thread_id, q1, q2):
        while not exit_flag:
            t1_lck.acquire()
            if not q1.empty():
                new_id = q1.get()
                t1_lck.release()
                # add id to t2_queue for threads2 to pick up
                t2_lck.acquire()
                t2_q.put(new_id)
                t2_lck.release()
                print('proc_q1 - new_id: {}'.format(new_id))
            else:
                t1_lck.release()

    @staticmethod
    def proc_q2(thread_id, q):
        t2_lck.acquire()
        if not q.empty():
            new_id = q.get()
            t2_lck.release()
            print('proc_q2 - new_id: {}'.format(new_id))
        else:
            t2_lck.release()


class MyT1(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, thread_id, q1, q2):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.thread_id = thread_id
        self.q1 = q1
        self.q2 = q2

    def run(self):
        print('Starting t1-thread {}'.format(self.thread_id))
        Scanner.proc_q1(thread_id=self.thread_id, q1=self.q1, q2=self.q2)
        print('Exiting t1-thread {}'.format(self.thread_id))


class MyT2(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, thread_id, q):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.thread_id = thread_id
        self.q = q

    def run(self):
        print('Starting t2-thread {}'.format(self.thread_id))
        Scanner.proc_q2(thread_id=self.thread_id, q=self.q)
        print('Exiting t2-thread {}'.format(self.thread_id))

# Create new threads
thread_pool_size = 5
t1_list = list()
t2_list = list()
t1_q = Queue(2 * thread_pool_size)
t2_q = Queue(2 * thread_pool_size)
t1_lck = threading.Lock()
t2_lck = threading.Lock()

exit_flag = False

for i in range(thread_pool_size):
    t1 = MyT1(thread_id=i, q1=t1_q, q2 = t2_q)
    t1.start()
    t1_list.append(t1)

    t2 = MyT2(thread_id=i, q=t2_q)
    t2.start()
    t2_list.append(t2)

# put data on the queue
t1_lck.acquire()
for i in range(10):
    t1_q.put(i)
t1_lck.release()

# Wait for empty queue
while not (t1_q.empty() and t2_q.empty()):
    pass

exit_flag = True

# wait for threads2 to finish
for t in t2_list:
    t.join()

# wait for threads1 to finish
for t in t1_list:
    t.join()

print("Done")
```

And here's the output (the script doesn't exit correctly)

```
Starting t1-thread 0
Starting t2-thread 0
Exiting t2-thread 0
Starting t1-thread 1
Starting t2-thread 1
Exiting t2-thread 1
Starting t1-thread 2
Starting t2-thread 2
Starting t1-thread 3
Exiting t2-thread 2
Starting t2-thread 3
Starting t1-thread 4
Exiting t2-thread 3
Starting t2-thread 4
Exiting t2-thread 4
proc_q1 - new_id: 0
proc_q1 - new_id: 1
proc_q1 - new_id: 2
proc_q1 - new_id: 3
proc_q1 - new_id: 5
proc_q1 - new_id: 4
proc_q1 - new_id: 6
proc_q1 - new_id: 7
proc_q1 - new_id: 8
proc_q1 - new_id: 9
```

Comment: Just to comment on your topic: Every(!) process contains a thread, it's the initially running one. Without this thread, you couldn't do anything, including starting other threads. This first threads is often not even special, btw.

Comment: Concerning your code: It's way too long and it depends on external services to access URL and download stuff. Replace this code with mocks to produce a minimal example as required per guidelines.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt, I updated the provided code with mocks. It's still long but much more manageable. Thank you for the readability guidance.

Answer (score 0):

I think the log output gives the answer.

The MyT2 threads exit before the the queue q2 is filled.

The exit condition is:

```
@staticmethod
def proc_q2(thread_id, q):
    ...
    if not q.empty():
    ...
```

Initially the queue q2 is empty, so the all MyT2 exit before the queue has data.

For that reason the program loops forever in the while loop:

```
...
while not (t1_q.empty() and t2_q.empty()):
...
```

BTW:
**Locking:** As far as I know, the Queue's get() and put() methods are synchronized. There is no need to acquire locks for en-queuing and de-queuing.

from the docs https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/queue.html:

```
17.7. queue — A synchronized queue class
```